# Storing raw private RSA key

Tags: ssh, rsa, pem

I was given a private RSA key from a colleague via Keybase.io, it looks something like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

blahx
blahy
blahz

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

he says I can just store this private key in my .ssh folder, so I have saved it in `.ssh/my-key.pem`

but it seems to be corrupted, when I run this:

```
$ openssl pkey -in ~/.ssh/my-key.pem -pubout -outform DER | openssl md5 -c

I get:
unable to load key
140006824072856:error:0906D066:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad end line:pem_lib.c:809:
```

anybody know why this might be? I saved the contents above directly into the my-key.pem file

Comment: Be sure to include the Private and Public keys in the file. And you should be generating your own private keys, I suggest a tool like `ssh-keygen`.

Comment: What about `ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/my-key.pem`

Comment: ssh questions are off-topic on stackoverflow. They belong on superuser.com